Read bmp header
here is my structure for header of BMP file
#ifndef _BMP_H
#define _BMP_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define PADDING_CHAR "\0"

/**
 * Structure contains information about the type, size, layout, dimensions
 * and color format of a BMP file. Size of structure is 54 bytes.
*/
struct bmp_header{
    uint16_t type;              // "BM" (0x42, 0x4D)
    uint32_t size;              // file size
    uint16_t reserved1;         // not used (0)
    uint16_t reserved2;         // not used (0)
    uint32_t offset;            // offset to image data (54B)
    uint32_t dib_size;          // DIB header size (40B)
    uint32_t width;             // width in pixels
    uint32_t height;            // height in pixels
    uint16_t planes;            // 1
    uint16_t bpp;               // bits per pixel (1/4/8/24)
    uint32_t compression;       // compression type (0/1/2) 0
    uint32_t image_size;        // size of picture in bytes, 0
    uint32_t x_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t y_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t num_colors;        // number of colors (0)
    uint32_t important_colors;  // important colors (0)
} __attribute__((__packed__));

/**
 * Reads BMP header from input stream
 *
 * Reads and returns BMP header from opened input stream. The header is located
 * at it's beginning. If the stream is not opened or it is corrupted, function
 * returns `NULL`.
 *
 * @param stream opened stream, where the image data are located
 * @return `bmp_header` structure or `NULL`, if stream is not open or broken
 */
struct bmp_header* read_bmp_header(FILE* stream);


and here my code, which read bmp header
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "bmp.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct bmp_header* read_bmp_header(FILE* stream){
    //проверка на успешное открытие файла
        if(stream == NULL) return NULL;
    

    //создание структуры для хранения заголовка БМП
    struct bmp_header* header = (struct bmp_header*)malloc(sizeof(struct bmp_header));
    if(header == NULL) return NULL;

    //проверка на чтение даных заголовка файла
    size_t succes_read = fread(header, sizeof(struct bmp_header), 1, stream);
    
    if(succes_read != 1){
        free(header);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    if(header->type != 0x4D42 || header->width <= 0 || header->height <= 0 || header->offset != 54 || header->dib_size != 40 || header->planes != 1 || (header->bpp != 1 && header->bpp != 4 && header->bpp != 8 && header->bpp != 24) || header->compression != 0 || header->image_size == 0 || header->x_ppm != 0 || header->y_ppm != 0 || header->num_colors != 0 || header->important_colors != 0){
        free(header);
        return NULL;
    }

    if(header->width > UINT32_MAX || header->height > UINT32_MAX){
        free(header);
        return NULL;
    }

    return header;
}


And my problem is when bot checks my code and this function, he do this check "Given the valid BMP stream When the function is invoked Then the image width must be valid And the image height must be valid" and idk what i need to do.
I try to check width and height but this code don`t work on check, which I write. If someine niw what i need to do, please help me.

I just had a checkup and the problem is still the same. I used the tips and nothing has changed.

The issue might be with the validation conditions for the image width and height in the read_bmp_header function. Let's revisit your code:
if(header->type != 0x4D42 || header->width <= 0 || header->height <= 0 || header->offset != 54 || header->dib_size != 40 || header->planes != 1 || (header->bpp != 1 && header->bpp != 4 && header->bpp != 8 && header->bpp != 24) || header->compression != 0 || header->image_size == 0 || header->x_ppm != 0 || header->y_ppm != 0 || header->num_colors != 0 || header->important_colors != 0){
    free(header);
    return NULL;
}

if(header->width > UINT32_MAX || header->height > UINT32_MAX){
    free(header);
    return NULL;
}

Your first condition checks if header->width and header->height are less than or equal to 0, but BMP images can have positive dimensions. Instead, you should validate that they are within reasonable bounds.
Try this instead:
if(header->type != 0x4D42 || header->width == 0 || header->height == 0 || header->offset != 54 || header->dib_size != 40 || header->planes != 1 || (header->bpp != 1 && header->bpp != 4 && header->bpp != 8 && header->bpp != 24) || header->compression != 0 || header->image_size == 0 || header->x_ppm != 0 || header->y_ppm != 0 || header->num_colors != 0 || header->important_colors != 0){
    free(header);
    return NULL;
}

if(header->width > UINT32_MAX || header->height > UINT32_MAX){
    free(header);
    return NULL;
}

These changes would ensures that the width and height are positive and reasonable values. If the header passes these conditions then it should be considered valid.

header->width > UINT32_MAX uint32_t width will hardly hold a value larger than UINT32_MAX.

@mmaarij your solution looks logical, but the check fails. Here what i have:
STDOUT: Running suite(s): read_bmp_header()
Reasons of failure
Segmentation fault
Return code of executed application is different than expected.

@USER Have you tried debugging the code to see exactly where the seg fault occurs? Without knowing where exactly the error errors, it's going to be hard to pinpoint the exact issue. Try adding print statements to see if the header fields hold valid data or garbage.
